# Scala: How to get the content of PortableDataStream instance from an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

As I want to extract data from binaryFiles I read the files using
`val dataRDD = sc.binaryRecord("Path")` I get the result as  `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream)]`

I want to extract the content of my files which is under the form of `PortableDataStream`

For that I tried: `val data = dataRDD.map(x => x._2.open()).collect()`
but I get the following error:

> java.io.NotSerializableException:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.HdfsDataInputStream

If you have an idea how can I solve my issue, please HELP!

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `PortableDataStream` is Serializable. That's what it is meant for. Yet, `open()` returns a simple `DataInputStream` (`HdfsDataInputStream` in your case because your file is on HDFS) which is not Serializable, hence the error you get.

In fact, when you open the `PortableDataStream`, you just need to read the data right away. In scala, you can use `scala.io.Source.fromInputStream`:

```scala
val data : RDD[Array[String]] = sc
    .binaryFiles("path/.../")
    .map{ case (fileName, pds) => {
        scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(pds.open())
            .getLines().toArray
    }}
```

This code assumes that the data is textual. If it is not, you can adapt it to read any kind of binary data. Here is an example to create a sequence of bytes, that you could process the way you want.

```
val rdd : RDD[Seq[Byte]] = sc.binaryFiles("...")
    .map{ case (file, pds) => {
        val dis = pds.open()
        val bytes = Array.ofDim[Byte](1024)
        val all = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Byte]()
        while( dis.read(bytes) != -1) {
            all ++= bytes
        }
        all.toSeq
    }}
```

See the [javadoc of `DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) for more possibilities. For instance, it possesses `readLong`, `readDouble` (and so on) methods.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried your solution, there is a '}' missing and also there should I edited `.toSeq()` to `.toSeq` otherwise it gives me `error: not enough arguments for method apply: (idx: Int)String in trait SeqLike`. Although the solution gives `ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job`

Comment: I had not tested all the code, sorry. I fixed my answer.

Comment: It actually does not work with `toSeq`, probably because it simply encapsulates the iterator based on the inputStream. `toArray` on the contrary actually extracts the data to put it in an array. I modified it in the answer. Thanks for your feedback ;)

Comment: Thanks @Oli for your response. The problem  still exist `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1`

Comment: OK, that's different. What kind of data are you reading? This was just an example for strings. If you read binary data, it will not work and you have to adapt the code...

Comment: yes it's binary data. The files has `.doc` extention

Comment: Therefore you should implement your own logic based on the `DataInputStream` using `read`, `readFully`, `readByte`...

Comment: I added an example to create a sequence of bytes.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your solution and it's working.The output is in the format of `RDD[Seq[Byte]]`. The output I should have is in format of `RDD[Seq[String]]`.  Is there any way to get the Output under this format? Many thanks

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the format of your data. You need to parse it. If it's a `.doc`, you could have a look at Apache POI. https://poi.apache.org/components/document/

Comment: Thank you @Oli for your response. I find also an apache for parsing called Apache Tika.

Comment: The code as shown did not work for me, since 1024 bytes were always appended to `all`, even if the last read had, only, say, 57 bytes.  See my answer for an alternative solution that does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
val bf    = sc.binaryFiles("...")
val bytes = bf.map{ case(file, pds) => {
    val dis = pds.open()
    val len = dis.available();
    val buf = Array.ofDim[Byte](len)
    pds.open().readFully(buf)
    buf
}}
bytes: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Byte]] = MapPartitionsRDD[21] at map at <console>:26

scala> bytes.take(1)(0).size
res15: Int = 5879609  // this happened to be the size of my first binary file
```